# Grafana Prometheus | Joining a metric with a static list of key-value pairs

Tags: csv, join, prometheus, grafana

There's a prometheus metric that returns memory consumed by each instance of an app in a specific data center:

```
memory_metric{appid="12354"}
```

So the above query will give me memory consumed by that appid on every data center, like

```
{dc: datacenter1, value: 20000}, {dc: datacenter2, value: 30000}
```

There's a number associated with each data center stored as a csv:

```
datacenter1: 12, datacenter2: 9, ...
```

I need to multiply the metric for every datacenter with that specific datacenter's number in the CSV above, then show the new value of each datacenter in a pie chart or a table.

I would also want to create another panel that sums the number recorded above.

I have already tried using grafana variables for storing and using the csv, but it doesn't really work

Comment: In short you need: mixed data source for your panel. First query Prometheus as you currently have (with type *Instant*); second - CSV data source with your values. Then apply transformation *Join by field*, and then transformation to multiply values.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your CSV into metrics with Prometheus recording rules (https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/):

```yaml
groups:
  - name: example
    rules:
    - record: give_this_metric_a_name
      expr: 1
      labels:
        dc: datacenter1
    - record: give_this_metric_a_name
      expr: 2
      labels:
        dc: datacenter2
    ...
    - record: give_this_metric_a_name
      expr: N
      labels:
        dc: datacenterN
```

Then you can use it in a query:

```
memory_metric{appid="12354"} * on(dc) group_left give_this_metric_a_name
```